# Rake db:migrate table already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why this is happening. I have the following migration:

```
def self.up
  create_table :leakages do |t|
    t.integer :feature_id
    t.integer :project_id
    t.float :total
    t.date :apt_date
  end
  add_index :leakages, [:feature_id, :apt_date]
end
```

When I run it for the first time it runs properly, but when I run the migration again then an error is thrown saying `leakages` table already exist. Why is this error occurring? I am using the mysql2 gem.

Comment: Why are you running the migration more than once?

Comment: Are you created the migration using Rails generator? Does your migration file has any timestamp prefix?

Comment: To added other tables

Comment: yes i am creating the migration using rails generator and it has timestamp prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a corresponding `self.down` in your `leakages` migration?  If not then you could change the method to `def change`, then you should be able to run `rake db:migrate:redo` which runs `db:migrate:down` then `db:migrate:up` for your last migration.

The reason you are seeing that message is because the table already exists.  `rake db:migrate` doesn't drop the table.  Basically it runs the migrations that have not run yet, for the current environment.

You might also be interested in reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#running-specific-migrations.

So to rerun the migration(i.e. db:migrate:down then db:migrate:up) you could run:

```
rake db:migrate:reset VERSION={your migration version}
```

Comment: i have a corresponding self.down method in my migration file
drop_table :leakages
yes but i added remove index in my self.down method because drop table will remove all the indexes automatically.

Comment: Our Database team altered the leakages table directly from the mysql database, that was the reason why the rake were not successfully completed. Now we corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You need to drop that table from the sql lite console (You will lost all the data contained in it)

1) Access the sql lite console, type in terminal

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3
```

2) Drop table (dont forget the last ; )

```
drop table table_name;
```

3) Exit sql lite console

```
.quit
```

4) run db:migrate again

```
bin/rake db:migrate
```

Hope it helps, it worked for me

Comment: If your migration shows as `down`, but the table exists in your DB, this is the only solution. You can't reset with proper migrations if you've switched branches because you can't `down` the migration in the first place (since it's considered `up`)

Answer (score 1):

I was updating Redmine from 2 to 3 and stuck with this problem. I've solved it with adding into a mysql `schema_migrations` table missing migrations names that rake was complaining of.

Here the bash script to fix it:

```
#!/bin/bash   
echo PLEASE run AS SUDO

mf=1
until [ -z "$mf" ]; do
echo +step start
# NOTE `bin/rake` is path to rake, use `rake` if installed globally, or put absolute path
mf=$(bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production" 2>&1 | grep -m1 -oP '(?<=db\/migrate\/)\w+(?=\.rb)')

  if [ ! -z "$mf" ] 
  then
    echo Insert migration: $mf
    echo "INSERT INTO \`schema_migrations\` (\`version\`) VALUES ('$mf');" | mysql -uroot -pSOjtHQobz6AF bitnami_redmine
  fi
  echo *step end
done
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this line of code in your existing file and again do rake db:migrate

```
   def down
      drop_table :leakages 
   end
```

It is because you have already create leakages table and migrate it. And again you are going to create it so for that first they shouldn't be leakages table. Then only it can create it. so, the leakages table must be drop before creating another table.